# set up a class-level logger

Tags: python, logging

I can easily configure the properties of a *global* logger:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s",
    datefmt="%d/%m/%Y ( %H:%M:%S )",
    stream=sys.stdout
)
```

How to achieve the equivalent thing at the *class-level*? (code below *doesn't* work)

```
import logging
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger.dictConfig({
            "level": logging.INFO,
            "format": "[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s",
            "datefmt": "%d/%m/%Y ( %H:%M:%S )",
            "stream": sys.stdout
        })
    def foo(self) -> None:
        self.logger.info("foooo ...")

c = SomeClass()
c.foo()
```

Here is the error I get:

```
$ python logger.py 2>&1 | grep "Error"
AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute 'dictConfig'
```

**EDIT**:
I look for a *single* initialization command, and not something like:

```
self.logger.setLevel(...)
self.logger.setFormatter(...)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may not like this answer, but in Python a class-level logger doesn't really make sense - unlike Java and C#, where the class is the unit of software decomposition, in Python the module is that unit. Therefore, `__name__` gives the name of the *module* and not any specific class defined in it.

Also, logging configuration (as regards handlers, formatters, filters etc.) is done at the *application* level and not the library level, so it should only really be done once under the `__name__ == '__main__'` condition, and not in random classes.

If you really need more granular logging than at the module level, use a logger name such as `__name__ + '.SomeClass'` for your loggers.

The logging documentation lists a number of [anti-patterns](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#patterns-to-avoid) which are contrary to best practice.

Comment: I don't agree with the anti-pattern statement *Code can always access a given logger instance by name using `logging.getLogger(name)`, so passing instances around and holding them as instance attributes is pointless.* Each method then needs to know what name to use, which can be complicated to support the possibility of the same class name being used in different modules. So you end up storing the name as a class attribute. Storing a reference to the logger instead avoids a lookup every time a method needs to log. This is an anti-patterns unusual case mentioned as an exception to the rule.

Comment: @Booboo The recommended approach is to use module-level loggers - all classes in a module would use the same logger. Of course people coming from a Java or C# or other class-oriented language wouldn't see it as an anti-pattern, and it's not an anti-pattern in those languages.

Comment: Yes, but the point of the question is to have *not* module-level debuggers but rather class-level debuggers where each class could have its own custom-tailored logger. That mean if the module has multiple such classes, you need multiple loggers and the reference to these multiple loggers **might as will live with each class**. The link above says *While there might be unusual cases where you’ll need to do this, in general there is no point because loggers are singletons.* In my opinion, this is one such unusual case where it makes sense, even if it is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Booboo in my experience, people often want class-level loggers because that's what they're used to in Java, C# environments - not because it's actually needed for functional reasons. Hence the counterpoint that I present.

Answer (score 2):

First, if you want it to be a class-level logger, I would define the logger as a class attribute. Second, I would use as the logger name when you call `logging.getLogger` not `__name__` but rather something that is unique to the class. Since you could be reusing the same class name in different modules, I would use a combination of `__name__` and the class name. To demonstrate this the second demo below has two instances of a class `SomeClass`, one in the script file, and one in a module named `workers`. These classes will instantiate loggers whose only difference is the format of the logging message. But first:

**Example With Multiple Logging Classes in the Same Script File**

```py
import sys
import logging

class SomeClass1:
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__ + '.SomeClass1')
    H = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    H.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    H.setFormatter(
        logging.Formatter(
            fmt="SomeClass1: [%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s: %(message)s",
            datefmt="%d/%m/%Y ( %H:%M:%S )"
        ))
    logger.addHandler(H)


    def foo(self) -> None:
        self.logger.warning("foooo ...")

class SomeClass2:
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__ + '.SomeClass2')
    H = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    H.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    H.setFormatter(
        logging.Formatter(
            fmt="SomeClass2: [%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s: %(message)s",
            datefmt="%d/%m/%Y ( %H:%M:%S )"
        ))
    logger.addHandler(H)


    def bar(self) -> None:
        self.logger.warning("bar ...")

c1 = SomeClass1()
c1.foo()
c2 = SomeClass2()
c2.bar()
```

Prints:

```None
SomeClass1: [30/05/2022 ( 09:14:06 )] WARNING: foooo ...
SomeClass2: [30/05/2022 ( 09:14:06 )] WARNING: bar ...
```

**Example With Same Class Name in Different Modules**

*workers.py*

```py
import sys
import logging

class SomeClass:
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__ + '.SomeClass')
    H = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    H.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    H.setFormatter(
        logging.Formatter(
            fmt="workers module: [%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s: %(message)s",
            datefmt="%d/%m/%Y ( %H:%M:%S )"
        ))
    logger.addHandler(H)


    def foo(self) -> None:
        self.logger.warning("foooo ...")
```

*script.py*

```py
import sys
import logging
import workers

class SomeClass:
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__ + '.SomeClass')
    H = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    H.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    H.setFormatter(
        logging.Formatter(
            fmt="Script File: [%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s: %(message)s",
            datefmt="%d/%m/%Y ( %H:%M:%S )"
        ))
    logger.addHandler(H)


    def foo(self) -> None:
        self.logger.warning("foooo ...")

c1a = SomeClass()
c1b = SomeClass()
c1a.foo()
c1b.foo()
c2 = workers.SomeClass()
c2.foo()
```

Prints:

```None
Script File: [30/05/2022 ( 09:23:02 )] WARNING: foooo ...
Script File: [30/05/2022 ( 09:23:02 )] WARNING: foooo ...
workers module: [30/05/2022 ( 09:23:02 )] WARNING: foooo ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you shouldn't bother mangling with the setFormatter, setLevel and whatnot method family, nor manage logger instances lifecycles besides single getLogger calls. If you need to go beyond the possibilities in `logging.basciConfig`, use the `logging.config` module!

Given your `SomeClass` lives in a module such that its import path (hence the value of the `__name__` variable) was `some.project.some.module`, somewhere during your application start you should configure all logging facilities like

```
import logging.config

logging.config.dictConfig({
    "version": 1,
    "formatters": {
        "default": {
            "class": "logging.Formatter",
            "format": "[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s",
            "datefmt": "%d/%m/%Y ( %H:%M:%S )",
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "stdout": {
            "formatter": "default",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "stream": sys.stdout,
        },
        "null": {
            "class": "logging.NullHandler",
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "some.project.some.module": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "propagate": True,
            "handlers": ["null"],
        },
    },
    "root": {
        "handlers": ["stdout"],
        "level": "INFO",
    },
})
```

It is easier for me to wrap my head around the logging module if only the topmost root logger is attached the handler actually writing to a file/stdout/whatever. This way other loggers only act as a way to adjust logging level per module and maybe inject special error handlers.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72435712/11715259 on a more detailed answer on why the logger is not special to your class but to its module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a better solution than this:

```
import sys
import logging
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        H = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        H.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        H.setFormatter(
            logging.Formatter(
                fmt="[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s: %(message)s",
                datefmt="%d/%m/%Y ( %H:%M:%S )"
            ))
        self.logger.addHandler(H)
    def foo(self) -> None:
        self.logger.warning("foooo ...")

c = SomeClass()
c.foo()
```