# How to organize logging of a class in a module?

Tags: python, class, logging, argparse

I have a class `Cache` and I want to implement logging in it. And I also want to be able to run a module with this class and logging from the command line with arguments (when argument `-s` is passed - in addition to logging to a file, there is also logging to stdout added).
This is my code:
**cache.py**

```
import argparse
import logging


# ArgumentParser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument("-s", "--stdout", action="store_true", help="logging to stdout")
args = parser.parse_args()

# Logger
formatter_for_stream = logging.Formatter(
    "[%(asctime)s]\t[%(levelname)-8s]\t[%(name)s]\t[%(filename)s:%(lineno)-3d] - %(message)s"
)
formatter_for_file = logging.Formatter(
    "%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(module)s:%(lineno)-3d - %(message)s"
)

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter_for_stream)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler("cache.log", mode="w", encoding="utf-8")
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter_for_file)

logger = logging.getLogger("LRUcache logger")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.propagate = False

if args.stdout:
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)


# Cache
class Cache:

    def __init__(self, limit: int = 10):
        self.limit = limit
        self.dict_cache = {}
        logger.info("Cache instantiated with limit `%s`", limit)
        logger.debug("Cache instantiated with limit=%s and dict_cache=%s", limit, self.dict_cache)
    ...
```

What is best way to organize code in **cache.py**? Should I put `# Logger` and `# ArgumentParser` in another module or in another classes? How do you usually implement logging in these cases?

Comment: often a parser is defined in a function which is called from the `if __name__ == __main__ ` block. That way it is defined in an importable script, but normally only run when the file is run as a script.

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72412687/set-up-a-class-level-logger/72435712#72435712

Comment: @VinaySajip thanks! So I should move logger setting to  ```__name__ == '__main__' ```  condition? And thats it?

Comment: @zaelcovsky Yes.